# cv2.seamlessClone() with OpenCV error: (-215:Assertion failed) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function 'locateROI'

Tags: python, opencv

Thanks for every answer:
I meet a error about

> cv2.seamlessClone(), cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.1)
>
> > /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:757: error: (-215:Assertion
> >     failed) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function 'locateROI'

my code is here:

```
 ret = []
    for i in range(num_samples):
        dstimg = transforms.functional.to_pil_image(x[i])
        dstimg = np.array(dstimg)#[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
        #print(dstimg.shape)
        #print(type(dstimg))
        #print(dstimg.bit_length())
        srcimg = transforms.functional.to_pil_image(output[i])
        srcimg = np.array(srcimg)#[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
        #print(srcimg.shape)
        #print(type(srcimg))
        #print(srcimg.bit_length())

        msk = transforms.functional.to_pil_image(mask[i])
        msk = np.array(msk)#[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
        #print(msk.shape)
        #print(type(msk))
        #print(msk.bit_length())
        #compute mask's center
        xs, ys = [], []
        for i in range(msk.shape[0]):
            for j in range(msk.shape[1]):
                if msk[i,j] == 255:
                    ys.append(i)
                    xs.append(j)
        xmin, xmax = min(xs), max(xs)
        ymin, ymax = min(ys), max(ys)
        center = ((xmax + xmin) // 2, (ymax + ymin) // 2)
        out = cv2.seamlessClone(srcimg, dstimg, msk, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
        out = out[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
        #print(out)
        #print(out.shape)
        out = transforms.functional.to_tensor(out)
        #print(out)
        #print(out.shape)
        out = torch.unsqueeze(out, dim=0)
        #print(out)
        #print(out.shape)
        ret.append(out)
    ret = torch.cat(ret, dim=0)
    return ret
```